# VPN client to Forcepoint/Stonesoft

Tags: ssl-vpn

I'm trying to get a Linux VPN client to connect to a SSL VPN with a Forcepoint firewall as endpoint. Also adding the previous name "Stonesoft" or "Stonegate", as most of the resources are found on the net under these.

I tried openvpn (fails early, as openvpn seems not to open the TLS session with a "Client Hello", therefore refused by the firewall).
My attempt with openconnect went a bit further. I ran:

```
openconnect --servercert pin-sha256:<blabla> <public endpoint hostname> --verbose --no-dtls
```

This on fails with:

```
POST https://<public endpoint hostname>
Attempting to connect to server <public IP>:443
Connected to <public IP>:443
SSL negotiation with <public hostname>
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on <public hostname>
Failed to read from SSL socket: Success.
Error fetching HTTPS response
GET https://<public hostname>
Attempting to connect to server <public IP>:443
Connected to <public IP>:443
SSL negotiation with <public hostname>
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on <public hostname>
Failed to read from SSL socket: Success.
Error fetching HTTPS response
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

Apart from the ironical "Failed: success" message, the logs on the firewall are not very helpful:

- SSL VPN connection - done
- SSL VPN connection - closed

The recommended way to work is to use IPsec (with strongswan). I can get it to work, but IPsec is often blocked by other firewalls, and is therefore not suitable for our usage.

Have any of you guys successfully mounted a VPN to Forcepoint/Stonegate from Linux? (Ubuntu, CentOS, or whatever else doesn't matter.)

Comment: You need to use a compatible client.. “SSL VPN” is not a protocol but only a rough technological categorization. // You may also want to read up on what Forcepoint SSL VPN actually is, because it appears to be a in-browser service only. No tunneling.

Comment: @DanielB It does provide tunneling as well (IPsec and SSL/VPN). However, I cannot find a compatible client. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Our vendor said that a client is coming in Q4 of 2020. Wait and see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An official VPN client for Linux is now out. It is available on their download page at https://support.forcepoint.com/Downloads (behind a sign up wall).